# $I_{n,m}=\int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)^m dx$, prove that $I_{n,m}=\frac{m}{n+1}I_{n-1,m+1}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $n$, $m$ be whole numbers, we define $I_{n,m}=\int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)^m dx$.

If $m\geq{1}$, prove that $I_{n,m}=\frac{m}{n+1}I_{n-1,m+1}$.

I am studying one variable calculus and I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  (Particularly integration by parts?)

Comment: This is the beta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: I think you slightly messed up between $\;n\;$ and $\;m\;$ in the last expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}u=(1-x)^m,&u'=-m(1-x)^{m-1}\\{}\\v'=x^n,&v=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\end{cases}\implies $$$${}$$

$$I_{n,m}=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^mdx=\overbrace{\left.\frac{x^{n+1}(1-x)^m}{n+1}\right|_0^1}^{=0}+\frac m{n+1}I_{n+1,m-1}$$

Prove that, in fact, **also**

$$I_{n,m}=\frac n{m+1}I_{n-1,m+1}$$